# Is the reputation calculation working correctly?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

Is reputation being calculated correctly, or am I reading the FAQ wrong?

See this screenshot of my user page:

[image]

3 x question up votes = 15, 7 x answer up votes = 70 = 85+ reputation as I read the FAQ.
But it's only 58.

Has anyone else noticed incorrect values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community Wiki answers [don't get reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq), which should be the difference.

The [reputation tab](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/454?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) lists each answer and the rep you did receive for it, add to that +2 for accepting an answer and the one rep all accounts start with, and you're at the magic 58.